# iframe-resizer not resize iframe with srcdoc html

Tags: javascript, iframe, iframe-resizer

I want to resize an the height of an iframe using html from srcdoc and I choosed to use the [iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) library.
But the iframe is never resizing and callbacks are never called.

Html :

```
<iframe scrolling="no" class="preview-iframe" id="iframe3" srcdoc="<html><head></head><body><p>TEST</p>
</body></html>"></iframe>
```

JS :

```
$('iframe#iframe3').iFrameResize({
  heightCalculationMethod: 'bodyScroll',
  log: true,
  resizedCallback: function () {
    console.log('resize');
  },
  initCallback: function () {
    console.log('init');
  },
});
```

[Here is my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Drakkin/j6aL2x81/1/)

Comment: Your sample code, including your fiddle, is really dumbed down. It is unclear where you are having problems.

Comment: I want the height of my iframe adapt to the content inside it, in my fiddle it should adapt the height to the 'TEST' paragrah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You srcdoc needs to have a link to the iframeResizer.contentWindow.js file in it.

Comment: Thanks that did it for me, here is my working jsfiddle : [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Drakkin/j6aL2x81/4/)